# Which has the higher absolute uncertainty and why? An electric vernier caliper or a micrometer?

Tags: experimental-physics, measurements, error-analysis, home-experiment

I was answering some questions in a textbook and it asked: Which one has the highest absolute uncertainty? A ruler, a voltmeter or vernier caliper?
I went with the ruler because the absolute uncertainty of a measurement (not a reading) is the same as its resolution and so the resolution of a ruler in 1mm. The vernier caliper I know has a resolution much less so why is the absolute uncertainty higher?

*I think maybe the question could have asked for the highest percentage uncertainty in which case I still wouldn't understand why it would be the vernier caliper and not the ruler.

The question I also wanted to ask was whether a micrometer has a larger uncertainty than a vernier caliper (I assumed after answering that question that larger measurements tend to have smaller uncertainties).

Thanks for any comments!